# php invoice number from date and some rule

Tags: php, date

There is a invoice number like this `T1702001`, the rule is start from 'T' and `date('y')`,`date('m')`,and the Id which just create in database.
So the following invoice number will be `T1702002`、`T1702003`...

I want to know how to set the last three number with $Id? I can't just add two `0` and $Id (ex. '00'.$Id)

My code is

`$invoe = 'T'.date('y').date('m').$Id;`

How can I set the rule?

Comment: you just use str_pad()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use  [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) pads a string to a new length.

str_pad(string,length,pad_string,pad_type)

```
<?php

 $Id=2;
 $invoe = 'T'.date('y').date('m').str_pad($Id,3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

 echo $invoe;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could Use `str_pad();`
Or You Could Just Add It:

```
$invoice = "T".date('y').date('m')."00".$Id;
echo $invoice;
```

Or include the 00 with your invoices. There is a good reason to leave space in your invoice numbers. Business Grows.